# How to change alert text while asking permission for Location in Cordova iOS app?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Does anyone know how to change the alert box string for the requesting current location? 
At the moment it displays the whole bundle name.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaeZC.png)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using - `cordova-plugin-geolocation`. For that, add below line in your `config.xml`

`<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>AppName would like to use your location.</string>
</edit-config>`

Or

Remove plugin: `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-geolocation`

Add again: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="AppName would like to use your location."`

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response! I tyred  adding the <edit-config> unfortunately it didnt work. Just to double check it goes under the <widget> in config.xml